# unable to install and view custom node in node-red

Tags: google-drive-api, node-red

I am trying to make a Google Drive Upload Node in Node-Red. The ones that exist don't really work for the application I have in mind. Its a PhotoBooth which get triggered and the photo is uploaded to Google Drive in a Public Folder

I have been following the sample Node creation steps, and seems like there is no error while I run node-red-start, and the steps to link my new node also work without errors. My code is committed here on github 
https://github.com/CuriosityGym/node-red-google-drive-upload

There are three files in the repo

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "node-red-google-drive-upload",
  "description": "Node Red Node for Uploading files to Google Drive Using Auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Rupin Chheda<rupin@curiositygym.com>",
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "Rupin Chheda",
      "email": "rupin@curiositygym.com"
    }    
  ],
  "main": "index.js",  
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/CuriosityGym/node-red-google-drive-upload"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/CuriosityGym/node-red-google-drive-upload/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "*",
    "readline": "*",
    "googleapis": "*",
    "google-auth-library": "*"

  }, 
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "node-red" : {
        "nodes": {
            "sample": "google-drive-upload.js"
        }
    }


}
```

**google-drive-upload.js**

```
    module.exports = function(RED) {
    function LowerCaseNode(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);
        var node = this;
        node.on('input', function(msg) {
            msg.payload = msg.payload.toLowerCase();
            node.send(msg);
        });
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("sample",LowerCaseNode);
}
```

**google-drive-upload.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    RED.nodes.registerType('sample',{
        category: 'function',
        color: '#a6bbcf',
        defaults: {
            name: {value:""}
        },
        inputs:1,
        outputs:1,

        label: function() {
            return this.name||"node-red-google-drive-upload";
        }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/x-red" data-template-name="sample">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="node-input-name"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="node-input-name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-red" data-help-name="sample">
    <p>A simple node that converts the message payloads into all lower-case characters</p>
</script>
```

I dont see the node visible under the nodes list on the left hand side in the node-red UI.

Please suggest what I can change to make this work. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi, this isn't an ideal question for stackoverflow as you are asking us to debug your code.

Comment: 1. unrelated to the issue, but you should follow the project naming guidelines for your node and use `node-red-contrib-` as the prefix.
2. the key question is where you have put your module - as that will determine whether the node-red runtime discovers it or not.
3. you may want to follow up on the mailing list or slack channel as a better venue for getting help on this type of question.

Comment: I understand. I put it up on the Mailing List. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-red/7kbWIUjKrPw